# Render Blazor components from JavaScript - How to Update a Blazor component parameter from JavaScript after component render

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am rendering a Blazor component in a HTML document from JavaScript. It is working 100% but once my Blazor component has rendered, I can not update one of the component parameters. This example is in the .Net 6 RC1 spec.  I would appreciate some help on two way binding of a parameter.

Code in my HTML file:

```
<script>
     async function loadComponent() {
    
      let containerElement = document.getElementById('my-counter');
    
      await Blazor.rootComponents.add(
       containerElement, 
      'counter', { currentCount: count });
    };

</script>
```

I want to update "Count" after the component is rendered.

See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-rc-1/#render-blazor-components-from-javascript) for the Microsoft .Net6 RC1 notes.

Answer (score 0):

I have only an idea for one way (blazor->JS).

You could define a JS-function that increment the counter and call it with blazor.

[calling a JS fcuntion](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).